# How to select if similar field count is the maximum in the table?

Tags: sql

I want to select from a table if row counts of similar filed is maximum depends on other columns.

As example

```
| user_id | team_id | isOk |   
|       1 |       1 |    1 |    
|       2 |       1 |    1 |   
|       3 |       1 |    1 |  
|       4 |       1 |    1 |   
|       5 |       2 |    1 |   
|       6 |       2 |    1 |   
|       7 |       2 |    1 |   
|       8 |       3 |    1 |   
|       9 |       3 |    1 |   
|      10 |       3 |    1 |   
|      11 |       3 |    0 |
```

So i want to select team 1 and 2 because they all have 1 value at isOk Column,
i tried to use this query

```
SELECT Team
FROM _Table1
WHERE isOk= 1
GROUP BY Team
HAVING COUNT(*) > 3
```

But still i have to define a row count which can be maximum or not.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
select team
from _table1
group by team
having min(isOk) = 1;
```

Comment: Exactly, Thank you very much. :))